# How to change style of multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a let's say ten thumb-pics of horses. And each time one horse gets clicked I would like its background to become grey. And the same when another horse gets clicked I would like that horse's background color to become grey and with it, all the other backgrounds to become back white.

If I do it like this

```
function changeBackHorse(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
   if (id == i) { 
     document.getElementById("horseThumb_" + id)
       .style.backgroundColor = '#888';
   }
  }
}
```

The background of the clicked horse changes. All I have to do now is to add an else statement so that when the ID isn't the same the backgrounds become white.

So I thought I thought this would work and have no idea why it doesn't. Nothing happens, though the ID passed is correct. (tested with alert(id)).

```
<span id="horseThumb_<%= horse_thumb.id %>"
 onclick="changeBackHorse('<%= horse_thumb.id %>');">
 <%= image ... %>
</span>
```

script:

```
function changeBackHorse(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 25 ; i++) {
   var el = document.getElementById("horseThumb_" + i);
   if (id == i){
    el.style.backgroundColor = '#888';
   } else {
    el.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
   }
  }
}​
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I tried changing it in various ways but can't figure out why it doesn't work. So any answers would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the actual markup your browser received (not the server side function you use to print those spans)?

Comment: <span id="horseThumb_1" class="hand positionLeft padding10" style="" onclick="changeBackHorse('1');"> sth </span> ... and so on. Maybe the problem is because not always the elements horseThumb_xx exists? And so my js in chrome throws an error: cannot read property 'style' of null. But that is because the number of horseThumbs change and not always are all there. But I thought that shouldn't stop the "for" function to stop cycling?

Comment: yes this is it. I didnt know that if the element wouldn't exist the error would stop the function from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm is that script running without throwing any error? I suspect the following statement:

```
for (i;i<25;i++) { ...
```

Make sure the count is correct. I've trim your code and it works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeBackHorse(id){
  var i=0;
  for (i;i<5;i++) {
   if (id == i){
    document.getElementById("horseThumb_"+id).style.backgroundColor='#888'
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById("horseThumb_"+i).style.backgroundColor='#fff'

   }
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
 changeBackHorse(1);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="horseThumb_0">horse 0</div>
<div id="horseThumb_1">horse 1</div>
<div id="horseThumb_2">horse 2</div>
<div id="horseThumb_3">horse 3</div>
<div id="horseThumb_4">horse 4</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was, yes, beacause my function tried to change some background colors of elements that didn't exist. And therefore didnt finish. Not to smart from me:). Edit: though i'm not sure then why it did work(it changed the background color) when there was no else statement? Even though in this case there should also be errors.

Comment: @necker with else it always goes into 'else' statement any try to access 'el.style' where el would be 'null'. If you drop 'else' statement it only goes in and access 'el' if the id match.